# Odd memory errors with dynamically allocated Stack and pointer arithmetic

Tags: c, memory-management, valgrind, heap-memory, pointer-arithmetic

I am attempting to build a stack using dynamic memory and pointer arithmetic to traverse around the stack.  I am getting errors I can not seem to solve.  The errors vary based on how I run the program.
1) if I run with just the args I get a segFault right before fClose on line 112, and no pFile is not NULL.
2) if I run with less than 20 items being fed to the stack everything works fine, it is only when I go to realloc the stack a second time I start getting errors
3) if I run it with more than 20 elements and valgrind it goes all the way through but with some read/write errors, primarily in pushStack.

I keep thinking I am getting close, but at this point I am more lost.  I am sure this may not be the best implementation for a stack, but I still can't figure out why it won't work some times.

Source Code:

```
    /**********************************************************************
CS2123 assignment2_stacks.c by Kyle Widmann
Purpose:
    This program takes a file supplied by user and reads each line, which is expected to be an int.  A stack is implemented using dynamic memory.  If the int is -99999 the stack is popped.  Otherwise the number is pushed onto the stack.  The stack increased by chunks of 10, but never decreases.
Command Parameters:
    assignment2 -i datafile.txt
Input:
    numbers supplied by datafile.txt from Command Line

    -The file is assumed to be nothing but integers.
    -All integers >-99999 will be pushed onto stack
    -Reading -99999 will cause the stack to pop
Results:
    Whenever the stack is popped the program prints elements remaning after the pop, and what integer was popped.  The program also prints whenver the stack size grows, as well as what the old and new stack sizes are.
Returns:
    0 - normal
Notes:

**********************************************************************/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

//Typedef for our stack
typedef struct stack{
    int iInfo;
    int iCount;
    int iStackSize;
}STACK;

//Define our definitions for True, False and Pop
#define TRUE 0
#define FALSE -1
#define POP -99999

//Declaration of functions
STACK *makeStack();
STACK *increaseStack(STACK *pStack);
int stackPush(int x, STACK **ppStack);
int stackPop(STACK **ppStack);
int stackEmpty(STACK *pStack);
int stackFull(STACK *pStack);
void getFile(int argc, char *argv[], char **ppszInputFile);
void readFile();

/**************************** MAIN FUNCTION ************************/
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    printf("Assignment 2 written by Kyle Widmann\n\n");

    //Pointer to input file from CLI, and stack to be used across program
    char *pszInputFile = NULL;
    STACK *pStack = makeStack();

    //Get the filename from the CLI
    getFile(argc, argv, &pszInputFile);

    //Open and read the file, pushing/popping as necessary
    readFile(pszInputFile, &pStack);

    //reset pStack to beginning of stack and free

    //GETTING ERRORS HERE????

    // printf("about to initialize iCount\n");
    int iCount = (int)pStack->iCount;
    // printf(" in Main. iCount: %d\n", iCount);
    pStack = pStack-(iCount-1);
    // printf("in Main. pStack: %p\n", pStack);
    free(pStack);

    return 0;
}

void readFile(char *pszInputFile, STACK **ppStack){
    char szInputBuffer[100];    //Input buffer to read from file
    int iInput;                 //variable to store the int read from file
    int iPop=0;                 //variable to store the popped int
    FILE *pFile;                //pointer to input file

    //Open the file
    pFile = fopen(pszInputFile, "r");
    if(pFile == NULL)
        printf("Error opening file;");

    printf("pFile addres: %p\n", pFile);

    while(fgets(szInputBuffer, 100, pFile) != NULL){
        if(sscanf(szInputBuffer, "%d[^\n]", &iInput) == 1){
            // printf("input: %d... \t", iInput);
            if(iInput == POP){
                // printf("about to Pop\n");
                iPop = stackPop(ppStack);
                if(iPop == FALSE){
                    printf("There was an error popping the stack\n");
                }
                else{
                    printf("Number of elements after popping: %d \t\t Integer popped: %d\n", (*ppStack)->iCount, iPop);
                }
            }
            else{
                printf("About to push %d \tStackSize: %d\tStackCount: %d\n", iInput, (*ppStack)->iStackSize, (*ppStack)->iCount);
                stackPush(iInput, ppStack);
            }
        }
    }

    // GETTING ERRORS HERE???

    // printf("pFile addres: %p\n", pFile);
    if(pFile != NULL){
        fclose(pFile);
        pFile = NULL;
    }
}

STACK *makeStack(){
    STACK *stack = (STACK *)malloc(sizeof(STACK)*10);
    stack->iInfo = 0;
    stack->iCount = 0;
    stack->iStackSize = 10;
    if(stack == NULL){
        printf("Error allocating stack\n");
    }
    return stack;
}

STACK *increaseStack(STACK *pStack){
    // printf("inside increase stack.  iCount: %d\tiStackSize: %d\n", pStack->iCount, pStack->iStackSize);

    //Set old stack size and old count of elements to redirect new stack after realloc
    int iOldCapacity = pStack->iStackSize;
    int iOldCount = (int)pStack->iCount;

    //set pStack back to the beggining of the HEAP
    pStack = pStack-(pStack->iCount-1);

    // printf("iCount after resetting to beginnign: %d\n", (pStack+iOldCount-1)->iCount);

    //Realloc pStack and add 10 spaces
    pStack = (STACK *)realloc(pStack, (sizeof(STACK)*(pStack->iStackSize + 10)));

    // printf("Printing Stack...\n");
    // int i;
    // for(i = 0; i<iOldCount; i++){
    //     printf("Address: %p\tiCount: %d\t, iStackSize: %d\n", pStack+i, (pStack+i)->iCount, (pStack+i)->iStackSize);
    // }

    //point pStack back to the last element pushed onto stack
    pStack = pStack + (iOldCount-1);

    //Update the size of stack
    pStack->iStackSize = pStack->iStackSize +10;

    // printf("Post realloc.  iCount: %d\tiStackSize: %d\n", pStack->iCount, pStack->iStackSize);

    //Print out that the stack has grown.
    printf("Stack capacity has grown from %d to %d\n", iOldCapacity, pStack->iStackSize);
    return pStack;
}

int stackPush(int x, STACK **ppStack){
    if(stackFull(*ppStack) == TRUE){
        //increase stack size
        *ppStack = increaseStack(*ppStack);
    }

    //set first element
    if(stackEmpty(*ppStack) == TRUE){
        (*ppStack)->iInfo = x;
        (*ppStack)->iCount = (*ppStack)->iCount + 1;
    }
    else
    {
        //Set the next element in stack
        (*ppStack+1)->iInfo = x;
        (*ppStack+1)->iCount = (*ppStack)->iCount +1;
        (*ppStack+1)->iStackSize = (*ppStack)->iStackSize;
        //ensure always pointing to top
        *ppStack = (*ppStack + 1);
    }

    return TRUE;
}

int stackPop(STACK **ppStack){
    int iPop;

    // if the stack is not empty
    if(stackEmpty(*ppStack) == FALSE){
        iPop = (*ppStack)->iInfo;
        (*ppStack-1)->iStackSize = (*ppStack)->iStackSize;

        //set the stack pointing to the previous element since current element was popped
        *ppStack = (*ppStack -1);
        return iPop;
    }

    return FALSE;
}

int stackEmpty(STACK *pStack){
    if(pStack->iCount > 0){
        return FALSE;
    }
    return TRUE;
}

int stackFull(STACK *pStack){
    if(pStack->iCount + 1 == pStack->iStackSize){
        return TRUE;
    }
    return FALSE;
}

/********************************* getFile ******************************
void getFile(int argc, char *argv[], char **ppszInputFile)
Purpose:
    Reads the CLI to assign file name containing student info to pszInputFile
Parameters:
    I   int argc                    the count of command line arguments
    I   char argv[]                 Array of the command line arguments
    I/O char **ppszInputFile        Double pointer to character string for the file name
Notes:
**************************************************************************/

void getFile(int argc, char *argv[], char **ppszInputFile)
{
    int i;

    for (i = 1; i < argc; i++)
    {
        // check for a switch
        if (argv[i][0] != '-')
            printf("Error: Switch expected");
        // determine which switch it is
        switch (argv[i][1])
        {
        case 'i':                   // Book File Name
            if (++i >= argc)
                printf("Error: Missing Switch\n");
            // check for too long of a file anme
            else
                *ppszInputFile = argv[i];
            break;
        default:
            printf("Error: Switch expected");
        }
    }
}
```

Valgrind Output:

```
valgrind --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all ./stacks -i data_a2.txt
==7116== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==7116== Copyright (C) 2002-2015, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==7116== Using Valgrind-3.11.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==7116== Command: ./stacks -i data_a2.txt
==7116== 
Assignment 2 written by Kyle Widmann

Size of STACK: 12   Size of stack: 12 Size of STACK*10: 120
pFile addres: 0x5203540
About to push 29    StackSize: 10   StackCount: 0
About to push 5     StackSize: 10   StackCount: 1
About to push 7295  StackSize: 10   StackCount: 2
About to push 103   StackSize: 10   StackCount: 3
About to push 394   StackSize: 10   StackCount: 4
Number of elements after popping: 4          Integer popped: 394
Number of elements after popping: 3          Integer popped: 103
About to push 48    StackSize: 10   StackCount: 3
About to push 12    StackSize: 10   StackCount: 4
About to push 839   StackSize: 10   StackCount: 5
About to push 55    StackSize: 10   StackCount: 6
Number of elements after popping: 6          Integer popped: 55
About to push 28    StackSize: 10   StackCount: 6
About to push 91    StackSize: 10   StackCount: 7
About to push 523   StackSize: 10   StackCount: 8
Number of elements after popping: 8          Integer popped: 523
About to push 289   StackSize: 10   StackCount: 8
About to push 32    StackSize: 10   StackCount: 9
inside increase stack.  iCount: 9   iStackSize: 10
iCount after resetting to beginnign: 9
Printing Stack...
Address: 0x52047f0  iCount: 1   , iStackSize: 10
Address: 0x52047fc  iCount: 2   , iStackSize: 10
Address: 0x5204808  iCount: 3   , iStackSize: 10
Address: 0x5204814  iCount: 4   , iStackSize: 10
Address: 0x5204820  iCount: 5   , iStackSize: 10
Address: 0x520482c  iCount: 6   , iStackSize: 10
Address: 0x5204838  iCount: 7   , iStackSize: 10
Address: 0x5204844  iCount: 8   , iStackSize: 10
Address: 0x5204850  iCount: 9   , iStackSize: 10
Post realloc.  iCount: 9    iStackSize: 20
Stack capacity has grown from 10 to 20
About to push 414   StackSize: 20   StackCount: 10
Number of elements after popping: 10         Integer popped: 414
About to push 829   StackSize: 20   StackCount: 10
About to push 21    StackSize: 20   StackCount: 11
About to push 9     StackSize: 20   StackCount: 12
About to push 45    StackSize: 20   StackCount: 13
About to push 299   StackSize: 20   StackCount: 14
About to push 101   StackSize: 20   StackCount: 15
Number of elements after popping: 15         Integer popped: 101
About to push 3     StackSize: 20   StackCount: 15
About to push 88    StackSize: 20   StackCount: 16
About to push 718   StackSize: 20   StackCount: 17
About to push 501   StackSize: 20   StackCount: 18
Number of elements after popping: 18         Integer popped: 501
About to push 39    StackSize: 20   StackCount: 18
About to push 89    StackSize: 20   StackCount: 19
inside increase stack.  iCount: 19  iStackSize: 20
iCount after resetting to beginnign: 19
Printing Stack...
Address: 0x5204920  iCount: 1   , iStackSize: 10
Address: 0x520492c  iCount: 2   , iStackSize: 10
Address: 0x5204938  iCount: 3   , iStackSize: 10
Address: 0x5204944  iCount: 4   , iStackSize: 10
Address: 0x5204950  iCount: 5   , iStackSize: 10
Address: 0x520495c  iCount: 6   , iStackSize: 10
Address: 0x5204968  iCount: 7   , iStackSize: 10
Address: 0x5204974  iCount: 8   , iStackSize: 10
Address: 0x5204980  iCount: 9   , iStackSize: 20
Address: 0x520498c  iCount: 10  , iStackSize: 20
Address: 0x5204998  iCount: 11  , iStackSize: 20
Address: 0x52049a4  iCount: 12  , iStackSize: 20
Address: 0x52049b0  iCount: 13  , iStackSize: 20
Address: 0x52049bc  iCount: 14  , iStackSize: 20
Address: 0x52049c8  iCount: 15  , iStackSize: 20
Address: 0x52049d4  iCount: 16  , iStackSize: 20
Address: 0x52049e0  iCount: 17  , iStackSize: 20
Address: 0x52049ec  iCount: 18  , iStackSize: 20
Address: 0x52049f8  iCount: 19  , iStackSize: 20
Post realloc.  iCount: 19   iStackSize: 30
Stack capacity has grown from 20 to 30
About to push 47    StackSize: 30   StackCount: 20
==7116== Invalid write of size 4
==7116==    at 0x400D30: stackPush (assignment2_stacks.c:162)
==7116==    by 0x400A1B: readFile (assignment2_stacks.c:101)
==7116==    by 0x400860: main (assignment2_stacks.c:60)
==7116==  Address 0x5204a10 is 0 bytes after a block of size 240 alloc'd
==7116==    at 0x4C2FD5F: realloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==7116==    by 0x400BAE: increaseStack (assignment2_stacks.c:133)
==7116==    by 0x400CDF: stackPush (assignment2_stacks.c:153)
==7116==    by 0x400A1B: readFile (assignment2_stacks.c:101)
==7116==    by 0x400860: main (assignment2_stacks.c:60)
==7116== 
==7116== Invalid write of size 4
==7116==    at 0x400D4A: stackPush (assignment2_stacks.c:163)
==7116==    by 0x400A1B: readFile (assignment2_stacks.c:101)
==7116==    by 0x400860: main (assignment2_stacks.c:60)
==7116==  Address 0x5204a14 is 4 bytes after a block of size 240 alloc'd
==7116==    at 0x4C2FD5F: realloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==7116==    by 0x400BAE: increaseStack (assignment2_stacks.c:133)
==7116==    by 0x400CDF: stackPush (assignment2_stacks.c:153)
==7116==    by 0x400A1B: readFile (assignment2_stacks.c:101)
==7116==    by 0x400860: main (assignment2_stacks.c:60)
==7116== 
==7116== Invalid write of size 4
==7116==    at 0x400D62: stackPush (assignment2_stacks.c:164)
==7116==    by 0x400A1B: readFile (assignment2_stacks.c:101)
==7116==    by 0x400860: main (assignment2_stacks.c:60)
==7116==  Address 0x5204a18 is 8 bytes after a block of size 240 alloc'd
==7116==    at 0x4C2FD5F: realloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==7116==    by 0x400BAE: increaseStack (assignment2_stacks.c:133)
==7116==    by 0x400CDF: stackPush (assignment2_stacks.c:153)
==7116==    by 0x400A1B: readFile (assignment2_stacks.c:101)
==7116==    by 0x400860: main (assignment2_stacks.c:60)
==7116== 
pFile addres: 0x5203540
about to initialize iCount
==7116== Invalid read of size 4
==7116==    at 0x40086F: main (assignment2_stacks.c:64)
==7116==  Address 0x5204a14 is 4 bytes after a block of size 240 alloc'd
==7116==    at 0x4C2FD5F: realloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==7116==    by 0x400BAE: increaseStack (assignment2_stacks.c:133)
==7116==    by 0x400CDF: stackPush (assignment2_stacks.c:153)
==7116==    by 0x400A1B: readFile (assignment2_stacks.c:101)
==7116==    by 0x400860: main (assignment2_stacks.c:60)
==7116== 
 in Main. iCount: 21
in Main. pStack: 0x5204920
==7116== 
==7116== HEAP SUMMARY:
==7116==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==7116==   total heap usage: 6 allocs, 6 frees, 6,272 bytes allocated
==7116== 
==7116== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==7116== 
==7116== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==7116== ERROR SUMMARY: 4 errors from 4 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Comment: `"%d[^\n]"` this is certainly not doing what you hope for.  Perhaps `"%d%*[^\n]"` or just simply `"%d"`?  Certainly other issues too

Comment: The file is guaranteed to be one integer per line.  I printed out the input as it is read from fgets and sscanf and it reads it correctly.

Comment: In that case, it will read correctly with `"%d"`.  `"%d[^\n]"` says to scan for an `int` then the characters `'['`, `'^'`, `'\n'`, `']'`.  It does not say, scan for an `int` then everything that is not a line-feed.

Comment: I changed that, still the same errors occuring, etiher way it is still running the same.

Comment: Your data structure is very odd.  You maintain a separate copy of the stack capacity and a separate item count per item, but these properties of your stack are not item-specific.  (Or at least they don't *need* to be.)  This requires your code to be a lot more complicated than is necessary.

Comment: Suggest improved allocation check.  Code does not test the result of `realloc()` and tests the result of `malloc()` too late. (after `stack->iInfo`).  Still likely not _the_ issue.

Comment: I don't see why your criterion for a full stack is `pStack->iCount + 1 == pStack->iStackSize`.  Because you use `iCount` as an inclusive *count*, not an *index*, that condition is true when there remains one unused position at the top of your stack.

Comment: In `makeStack()`, it's good that you check for allocation failure.  It's bad that you start using the pointer returned by `malloc()` before the check.  It's also bad that all you do in the event of a failure is print a diagnostic.  The program ought to abort in that case, because it has no stack to work with.

Comment: JohnBollinger you are correct.  The full stack criteria was wrong.  Still no change in the errors I am getting though.  Also added the check for NULL ptr after malloc and realloc and no change with that either.

Comment: Aside: your definitions of `TRUE` and `FALSE` buck the convention. In C `0` is false and any other value is true. Boolean definitions have been introduced to C which also contradict your definitions (however I am not a believer in formal boolean types in C).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your `increaseStack()` function, and it relates to my observation in comments that you keep a lot of redundant data.  Note in particular that the problem occurs immediately after your second stack expansion -- this is no coincidence.

Here is a high-level description of the behavior of your `increaseStack()` function:

1. Record the stack capacity and number of elements, as indicated by the provided element pointer.
2. Adjust the element pointer to point to the bottom-most stack element, using the recorded element count.
3. Reallocate, choosing a new capacity based on the capacity indicated by the current element pointer (now pointing at the bottom-most element).
4. Adjust the stack pointer to point to the element of the reallocated space corresponding to the one that it pointed to on function entry.
5. Update the stack capacity recorded in the element pointed to by the stack pointer.

Study steps 3 and 5 carefully, and consider why your approach would work for the first stack expansion, but not the second.

I suspect I know what your first inclination for a solution will be, but resist it.  Instead, give a thought to how you could design this better.  In particular, what benefit do you get from having a separate `iCount` and `iStackSize` for every element?  (Hint: none.)

I suggest changing your `struct stack` like so:

```
typedef struct stack{
    int *iInfo;
    int iCount;
    int iStackSize;
}STACK;
```

Then, maintain just one `struct stack`, and perform your dynamic allocation / reallocation on its `iInfo` member.  Use simple indexing syntax based on `iCount` to store values in and retrieve them from the space pointed to by `iInfo`.

Comment: ok I definitely see what you are saying.  I initially wanted to do that but I couldn't figure out how to implement it.  To this point I have only seen stacks that use fixed arrays.  Back to the drawing board though, I will figure it out and give the check as soon as I get it.  Thanks a lot!

Comment: so I implemented it using a variable array in the struct like so:
`typedef struct stack{
    int iCount;
    int iStackSize;
    int iInfo[];
}STACK;`
I couldn't figure out how to use the int* in the array and get it to increment.  Definitely an infinitely simpler solution, though, thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: @KyleWidmann, I'm glad you have found a solution.  What you are now using is a `struct` with a "flexible array member".  It is a viable alternative, but it requires you to reallocate the *whole `struct`* to increase the stack size.  If you had gone with the ordinary `int *` then you would reallocate only the space for the elements, pointed to by `iInfo`, not the whole `struct`.  That has the advantage that it can work when the `struct` itself is not dynamically allocated, and also that it is compatible with C90.  But the main thing is that your code now works.